Creating a ratio from data assigned to two contestants in python
I have a problem with a bit of script that supposed to take some data - namely player/score numbers and create a ratio results for further analysis.
Colud someone pleasee help me - it's probably a minor mistake but I'm not too experienced and just trying to adjust what I found on the net.
My data looks like this:
Player1          1               
Player2          1           
-------------------------------------------
Player3          5         
Player4          1        
-------------------------------------------
Player4          2        
Player1          3               
-------------------------------------------
Player2          2           
Player5          1             
-------------------------------------------
Player5          2             
Player4          3       
-------------------------------------------
Player1          3               
Player3          1         
-------------------------------------------
Player3          2         
Player5          3                        
-------------------------------------------
Player4          3        
Player2          1          
-------------------------------------------
Player2          3           
Player1          2              
-------------------------------------------
Player4          1        
Player3          4         
-------------------------------------------
Player1          3               
Player4          2        
-------------------------------------------
Player5          3             
Player2          4          
-------------------------------------------
Player4          3        
Player5          2             
-------------------------------------------
Player3          3         
Player1          4               
-------------------------------------------
Player5          3             
Player3          2         
-------------------------------------------
Player2          1           
Player4          4        
-------------------------------------------
Player3          5         
Player2          2           
-------------------------------------------
Player1          1               
Player5          2             
-------------------------------------------

The final results are quite satisfying in some cases and in some of them, the results are opposite to the input data.
These are the results - for convinience I have marked the wrong numbers with an "i" as for "incorrect".
The exclamation mark is placed net to the score that is completely with "no grounds"  to exist:
Player1 Player2 1:1
Player3 Player4 5:1
Player4 Player1 3:2 i
Player2 Player5 2:1
Player5 Player4 3:2 i
Player1 Player3 3:1
Player3 Player5 3:2 i
Player4 Player2 3:1
Player2 Player1 3:2
Player4 Player3 4:1 i
Player1 Player4 3:1 i!
Player5 Player2 4:3 i
Player4 Player5 3:2
Player3 Player1 4:3 i
Player5 Player3 3:2
Player2 Player4 4:1 i
Player3 Player2 5:2
Player1 Player5 2:1 i

I'm not a coder in a real sense and all I could figure out is that there is something wrong with transform_results function
and I can think of the following reasons , with very little knowledge to fix them...:
-incorrect comparison logic: If the scores are not correctly compared, the resulting ratios might be incorrect.
-order of players and scores: If the order of players and scores is not maintained correctly, the output might not match the expected results.
And that is the piece of code I used:
I wouldn't ask you to rewrite to much but maybe that is some small glitch to be corrected easily?
I'll appreciate every insight this work is needed for statistical analysis that I expect to earn money on one day, but not just yet, in case you wondered... ;)
Thank you very much in advance and all the best:)

# Function to read data from a text file
def read_data_from_file(file_name):
    data = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line and not line.startswith('-'):
                data.append(line.split())
    return data

# Function to convert direct results to ratio
def transform_results(data):
    results = []
    for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
        player1, score1 = data[i][0], data[i][1]
        player2, score2 = data[i + 1][0], data[i + 1][1]
        if player1 != player2:
            if score1 > score2:
                ratio = f"{score1}:{score2}"
            else:
                ratio = f"{score2}:{score1}"
            results.append([player1, player2, ratio])
        return results

# Function to write results to a text file
def write_results_to_file(results, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        for row in results:
            file.write(' '.join(row) + '\n')

# File paths
input_file = 'C:/Users/M/Desktop/Test.txt'
output_file = 'C:/Users/M/Desktop/Results.txt'

# Read data from input file
data = read_data_from_file(input_file)

# Transform results into ratio
results = transform_results(data)

# Write results to output file
write_results_to_file(results, output_file)

print("Transformation of results completed successfully.")

Additionally:
>>> # Function to read data from a text file
>>> def read_data_from_file(file_name):
...     data = []
...     with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
...         for line in file:
...             line = line.strip()
...             if line and not line.startswith('-'):
...                 data.append(line.split())
...     return data
...
>>> # Function to convert direct results to ratio
>>> def transform_results(data):
...     results = []
...     for i in range(0, len(data)):
...         player1, score1 = data[i][0], data[i][1]
...         player2, score2 = data[i][2], data[i][3]
...         if not player1 == player2:
...             if score1 > score2:
...                 ratio = f"{score1}:{score2}"
...                 results.append([player1, player2, ratio])
...             else:
...                 ratio = f"{score2}:{score1}"
...                 results.append([player2, player1, ratio])
...     return results
...
>>> # Function to write results to a text file
>>> def write_results_to_file(results, file_name):
...     with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
...         for row in results:
...             file.write(' '.join(row) + '\n')
...
>>> # File paths
>>> input_file = 'C:/Users/M/Desktop/Test.txt'
>>> output_file = 'C:/Users/M/Desktop/Results.txt'
>>>
>>> # Read data from input file
>>> data = read_data_from_file(input_file)
>>> results = transform_results(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in transform_results
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> write_results_to_file(results, output_file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'results' is not defined
>>>
>>> print("Transformation of results completed successfully.")


Sorry for the formatting - it was supposed to be a list of results and the score data has huge size. I don't know  why! Could somebody just fixm it to look better, and also coul someone show the source file wiyth them dashes as I intended? Thank you in advance

Are you always supposed to display them with the winner first?  Notice that the code in transform_results swaps the SCORES if the second is larger, but does not swap the NAMES.  That's the key problem.

No I have not noticet it, thanks a lotTim and thank you for your interest in this matter. I will run the code as soon as I get home from work.

# Function to read data from a text file
def read_data_from_file(file_name):
    data = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line and not line.startswith('-'):
                data.append(line.split())
    return data

# Function to convert direct results to ratio
def transform_results(data):
    results = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        player1, score1 = data[i][0], data[i][1]
        player2, score2 = data[i][2], data[i][3]
        if not player1 == player2:
            if score1 > score2:
                ratio = f"{score1}:{score2}"
                results.append([player1, player2, ratio])
            else:
                ratio = f"{score2}:{score1}"
                results.append([player2, player1, ratio])
    return results

# Function to write results to a text file
def write_results_to_file(results, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        for row in results:
            file.write(' '.join(row) + '\n')

# File paths
input_file = 'Test.txt'
output_file = 'Results.txt'

# Read data from input file
data = read_data_from_file(input_file)
results = transform_results(data)
write_results_to_file(results, output_file)

print("Transformation of results completed successfully.")


Thank you very much for fixing my upload

If my answer was useful, then please do not forget to put a green check mark next to it :)

the green check mark is for answers that solve the question, not for anything less than that.

I'm talking about solving the question

I'm sorry I didn't  answer earlier!

Hi Qion! I'm sorry I didn't answer earlier. There seem to be some problem I do not understand - I only changed the pathsm for files, nothing more, I will try to upload the interpreter answers

https://fastupload.io/36f3bbfed67456c3
